# custom built in intents with Google assistant SDK

Tags: dialogflow-es, voice, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to extend my voice technologies experience after working with Amazon Alexa. 
Is it possible to use my Raspberry Pi based assistant handle the custom built-in intents like:
 - Hey Google, play with the dog;
 - Hey Google, make me a coffee;
 - Hey Google, clean the room;

As I know the google has pretty the same way of deep linking of command and in the usual way user needs to say something like: 
 - Hey Google, talk to my concierge play with the dog;
 - Hey Google, talk to my concierge make me a coffee;
 - Hey Google, talk to my concierge clean the room;

Is there a way to make direct calls to some concrete action without calling its name using Actions SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you are using the Google Assistant SDK, you can register [custom device actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/device-actions-overview) which will allow you to get callbacks based on certain queries that you say, including the ability to pull parameters that may have been said.